# Calculate the Number of Mondays in a Month

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the number of weeks within a month.

The first week of January 2014 starting from the first Monday is the 6th. So, January has 4 weeks. 
The first week of March 2014 starting from the first Monday is the 3rd. So, March has 5 weeks.

I want to know how many weeks there are in a month counting from the first Monday, not the first day.

How do I do this?

I have this code but it is used to get week number of the month for specific dates.

```
public int GetWeekNumberOfMonth(DateTime date)
{
    date = date.Date;
    DateTime firstMonthDay = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
    DateTime firstMonthMonday = firstMonthDay.AddDays((DayOfWeek.Monday + 7 - firstMonthDay.DayOfWeek) % 7);
    if (firstMonthMonday > date)
    {
        firstMonthDay = firstMonthDay.AddMonths(-1);
        firstMonthMonday = firstMonthDay.AddDays((DayOfWeek.Monday + 7 - firstMonthDay.DayOfWeek) % 7);
    }
    return (date - firstMonthMonday).Days / 7 + 1;
}
```

Comment: So you actually want the number of Mondays in a given calendar month?

Comment: do u have any code to show us

Comment: I just want to know how much week in month, but counted from the first Monday, not the first date.

Comment: @Enkhay: Under what situations would that be different to "the number of Mondays in the month"? (That's a simpler concept to compute, at least.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

Get the number of days in the current month, and find the first day. For each day in the month, see if the day is a Monday, if so, increment the value.

```
public static int MondaysInMonth(DateTime thisMonth)
{
    int mondays = 0;
    int month = thisMonth.Month;
    int year = thisMonth.Year;
    int daysThisMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    DateTime beginingOfThisMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < daysThisMonth; i++)
        if (beginingOfThisMonth.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            mondays++;
    return mondays;
}
```

You can use it like this with the current date:

```
Console.WriteLine(MondaysInMonth(DateTime.Now));
```

**Output:**
*4*

or with any month you choose:

```
Console.WriteLine(MondaysInMonth(new DateTime(year, month, 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i want, this code work for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Just correction to Cyral code :

i must start from 0 as he is using AddDays method .

Reason :the above example returns 5 for NOV and 4 for DEC which is wrong..

Edited code :

```
    public static int MondaysInMonth(DateTime thisMonth)
{
    int mondays = 0;
    int month = thisMonth.Month;
    int year = thisMonth.Year;
    int daysThisMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    DateTime beginingOfThisMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < daysThisMonth; i++)
        if (beginingOfThisMonth.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            mondays++;
    return mondays;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use that code, but in some cases it didn't work. So I found this code on MSDN.

```
public static int MondaysInMonth(this DateTime time)
    {
        //extract the month
        int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(time.Year, time.Month);
        var firstOfMonth = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, 1);
        //days of week starts by default as Sunday = 0
        var firstDayOfMonth = (int)firstOfMonth.DayOfWeek;
        var weeksInMonth = (int)Math.Ceiling((firstDayOfMonth + daysInMonth) / 7.0);

        return weeksInMonth;
    }
```

I created it like a extension method, so I can use like that:

```
var dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
var weeks = dateTimeNow.MondaysInMonth();
```

Answer (score 0):

The faster method without looping

```
private static double GetDaysCount(DateTime sampleDate, int DayOfWeekToMatch)
{
    int FirstDayOfMonth = (int)(new DateTime(sampleDate.Year, sampleDate.Month, 1).DayOfWeek);

    int FirstOccurrenceOn = 0;

    if (FirstDayOfMonth < DayOfWeekToMatch)
        FirstOccurrenceOn = DayOfWeekToMatch - FirstDayOfMonth + 1;
    else
        FirstOccurrenceOn = (7 - FirstDayOfMonth) + DayOfWeekToMatch + 1;

    int totalDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(sampleDate.Year, sampleDate.Month);

    return Math.Ceiling((totalDays - FirstOccurrenceOn) / 7.0f);
}
```

Comment: At a glance it looks like you may have missed declaration of ExpiryDate. I did not come across a library instance of this expression which would probably make this answer hard to consume as a beginner.

Comment: Yeah I didn't notice it too, that code was copied from one of my earlier projects. I've updated a cleaner code.

Comment: This code has issues when the DayOfWeekToMatch falls on the first and/or the last date of a given month.